# PyQt change element in .ui file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have the pyqt-based app and design in .ui file. They communicate with each other using signals and slots, but I have a need to change the properties of the elements in the design. Is it possible to do this? Pseudo-code what I need:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def click_my_btn(self, sender):
    button = QtGui.QPushButton(button)
    button.hide()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access elements from .ui designs by their names. E.g. there is a design for main window with one button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  ...
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn"/>
  ...
 </widget>
</ui>
```

You init widget object with it:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('window.ui', self)

main_window = MainWindow()
```

Then from your method you can get access to that button:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def click_my_btn(self, sender):
    main_window.btn.hide()
```